# What does a "version file" look like?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I've been googling this for ages now without results. The [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) manual says:

```
--version-file=FILE
    add a version resource from FILE to the exe
```

That sounds nice. I want to put version information in my executables. The problem is that I have no clue what a "version file" looks like and I can't find a single example of one that I can use. I would consider an example of a version file as an acceptable answer to this question.

---

#### What I've tried

The manual also says:

> **version**
>   Windows NT family only. version='myversion.txt'. Use
>   GrabVersion.py to steal a version resource from an executable, and
>   then edit the ouput to create your own. (The syntax of version
>   resources is so arcane that I wouldn't attempt to write one from
>   scratch.)

I have attempted this with countless executable files from my system now. I just keep getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\utils\GrabVersion.py", line 42, in 
    vs  = versioninfo.decode(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\utils\versioninfo.py", line 33, in decode
    nm = win32api.EnumResourceNames(h, RT_VERSION)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

on executables that has no version information, and:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\utils\GrabVersion.py", line 43, in 
    print vs
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\utils\versioninfo.py", line 147, in __repr__
    % (indent, self.ffi.__repr__(indent), indent,
  File "C:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\utils\versioninfo.py", line 251, in __repr__
    "filevers=%s," % fv,
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

On the rest.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just had a quick look at the sources.  It appears that the version file is expected to be Python source itself as the provided version file with be read and then `eval`'ed.

The `GrabVersion.py` script appears to generate errors as you've already found, so I modified the `__repr__` function of `FixedFileInfo` to manually convert tuple arguments to strings.

The Windows `cmd.exe` has a Windows version resource embedded, here's the output from `GrabVersion.py` which you would save to a file and feed to PyInstaller.

```
VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
    filevers=(6, 1, 7601, 17514),
    prodvers=(6, 1, 7601, 17514),
    mask=0x3f,
    flags=0x0,
    OS=0x40004,
    fileType=0x1,
    subtype=0x0,
    date=(0, 0)
    ),
  kids=[
    StringFileInfo(
      [
      StringTable(
        u'040904B0',
        [StringStruct(u'CompanyName', u'Microsoft Corporation'),
        StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'Windows Command Processor'),
        StringStruct(u'FileVersion', u'6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)'),
        StringStruct(u'InternalName', u'cmd'),
        StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'\xa9 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.'),
        StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'Cmd.Exe'),
        StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'Microsoft\xae Windows\xae Operating System'),
        StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'6.1.7601.17514')])
      ]), 
    VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

I haven't tried setting a version resource with PyInstaller so I'm not sure if this will work, I'd be interested in your feedback.

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly except for one small thing - the "product version" in the resulting executable is blank. It's no big deal for me though.

Comment: Funny, The product version worked fine for me.  Make sure you get this line (about the 4th line): `prodvers=(0, 0, 1, 0),` and use commas instead of periods.  I don't know what difference it makes, but the product version appears again in the stringtable (about line 24): `StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'0.0.1.0')])` where periods are used.

Comment: ProductVersion is blank for me as well in the .exe.

Comment: Note that the strings have to be (double) null-terminated, otherwise you might get hideous problems. See also [Compiler error when using GetStringFileInfo in InnoSetup on application created with PyInstaller](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29341371/850848).

Comment: Same result here.  Everything worked great, except Product Version is blank.  Anyone figure this out?

Comment: I figured out the ProductVersion issue.  It needs to be in the exact same format as as prodvers.  You can't use periods, you must use commas, and they must have spaces between them.  FileVersion on the other hand can use your own format.

Comment: Hi I want to add Legal Trademark property how to add?

Comment: I'm unclear where this VSVersionInfo is located.  Do you add this yourself to a version file?  How would ever construct this?  I'd like to learn more about version files and don't feel this answer was clear enough.

Answer (score 37):

I might be missing this in the previous answers, or maybe PyInstaller has been updated since these answers were originally provided, but the current docs for PyInstaller teach a [fairly simple method for this](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#capturing-windows-version-data) using a command-line tool provided with PyInstaller (though I missed this section the first few times I looked to the docs).

Point this tool at an .exe file on your system that has "good looking" version info, and it will create a human-readable, commented, editable version resource file that you can use as a starting point.

```
pyi-grab_version executable_with_version_resource
```

which by default writes a file `file_version_info.txt` to the working directory.

Running the above on my local copy of svn.exe produces:

```
# UTF-8
#
# For more details about fixed file info 'ffi' see:
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997.aspx
VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
# filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
# Set not needed items to zero 0.
filevers=(1, 9, 7, 30920),
prodvers=(1, 9, 7, 30920),
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the valid bits 'flags'r
mask=0x3f,
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file.
flags=0x0,
# The operating system for which this file was designed.
# 0x4 - NT and there is no need to change it.
OS=0x4,
# The general type of file.
# 0x1 - the file is an application.
fileType=0x1,
# The function of the file.
# 0x0 - the function is not defined for this fileType
subtype=0x0,
# Creation date and time stamp.
date=(0, 0)
),
  kids=[
StringFileInfo(
  [
  StringTable(
    u'040904B0',
    [StringStruct(u'CompanyName', u'Apache Software Foundation'),
    StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'svn'),
    StringStruct(u'FileVersion', u'1.9.7'),
    StringStruct(u'InternalName', u'SVN'),
    StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'Copyright (c) The Apache Software Foundation'),
    StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'svn.exe'),
    StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'Subversion'),
    StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'1.9.7 (r1800392)')])
  ]), 
VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

edit this to your purpose, and feed it back to PyInstaller as a `--version-file`, e.g.

```
pyinstaller [options] myscript.py --version-file file_version_info.txt
```

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Link updated:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=windows%20version#capturing-windows-version-data

Answer (score 9):

Create your Version file using an earlier answer save it as `version.rc`

Locate the `filename.spec` file open it.
next in that script, locate the:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,...)
```

at the end of that entire section add this piece of code to automatically embed the version information on your exe file

```
version='version.rc'
```

Save it and then launch pyinstaller again and this time run the installer using this code:

```
pyinstaller filename.spec
```

this will not only create the exe file itself but also include all of your version information as well.

**In case you may not have thought about it, replace the `filename` with your program's filename**

Answer (score 6):

I found on the Internet a simple package for creating a version file: https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller-versionfile/#description  . After installing it according to the information from the link, it is enough to apply a simple and readable code:

```
import pyinstaller_versionfile

pyinstaller_versionfile.create_versionfile(
    output_file="versionfile.txt",
    version="1.2.3.4",
    company_name="My Imaginary Company",
    file_description="Simple App",
    internal_name="Simple App",
    legal_copyright="© My Imaginary Company. All rights reserved.",
    original_filename="SimpleApp.exe",
    product_name="Simple App"
)
```

As a result of its operation, we obtain a file, e.g.  as in the answer of @mac . The file is ready to use in pyinstaller.

Answer (score 4):

I had problems with Pyinstaller *--version-file* option in Python 3 and I solve it using [Simple Version Resource Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows).

With this tool you can show the content of any *version resource*, just use the /vo option with any executable file: `verpatch.exe /vo c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

To add a **new** *version resource* to an executable file, just follow this example:

```
verpatch.exe script.exe 1.0.0.0 /va /pv 1.0.0.0 /s description "Your product description" /s product "Your product name" /s copyright "Your company name, 2016" /s company "Your company name"
```

Comment: sharing from my experience after testing this tool, it seems to add the information but if you plan to add digital signature afterward with the tool `signtool.exe` then `verpatch.exe` mess things up and causes signature error. the other answer providing `--version-file` worked successfully with signtool for me

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the version file uses Python code, so you can give it the `.py` extension rather than `.rc`.

This will allow you to see it formatted nicely in your IDE, to check for errors (ignore "Unresolved References", of course), and to do anything else Python allows you to do.