# Compiler error when using GetStringFileInfo in InnoSetup on application created with PyInstaller

Tags: python, installation, inno-setup, pyinstaller, fileversioninfo

I created version info file as described here - [What does a "version file" look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624245/what-does-a-version-file-look-like)
and do got EXE-file with all version information.

My issue is next, when I try to build setup file with InnoSetup, I'm getting an error:

> Error on line 65 in d:\installation\Source\setup_script.iss: Missing
>   closing quote on parameter "Name"

**line 65:**

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#VerInfoProductName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#ExeFileName}.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
```

Definition of `VerInfoProductName` below

```
#define VerInfoProductName GetStringFileInfo(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "..\..\dist\app\testapp.exe", "ProductName")
```

Details are attached [in archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4o182b60ywnxbh7/Source.7z?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something in your application version info strings that confuses the Inno Setup pre-processor. Your code works with other applications.

The pre-processor loads the `ProductName` in a way that resulting variable is actually longer than the value, the remaining space filled with some garbage that later confuses the compiler.

You can workaround it by using `{#SetupSetting('AppName')}` instead of `{#VerInfoProductName}`. This of course assumes that `AppName` is set to `{#VerInfoProductName}`.

Another way is to round-trip the string via an INI file:

```
#expr WriteIni("C:\path\xxx.ini", "xxx", "xxx", VerInfoProductName)
#define VerInfoProductName ReadIni("C:\path\xxx.ini", "xxx", "xxx")
```

---

Actually in normal Windows resource files (`.rc`), one has to explicitly null-terminate the version info strings (note the `\0`):

```
VALUE "ProductName", "TestProductName\0"
```

The resulting null (`\0`) character is explicitly stored in the resulting binary. So in the end there are two null characters in the resulting binary (four 0 bytes in UTF-16 encoding). This is common WinAPI format when multiple values are allowed. The null character is values separator, the double-null terminates the sequence.

Your `TestApp.exe` is missing that second null. I can see that in a hex dump. I'm pretty sure that this is the primary cause of your problem.