# Set Product Version Number metadata on .exe file with PyInstaller

Tags: python, windows, metadata, exe, pyinstaller

I've been looking everywhere on the [PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and on search engines but I cannot figure this out:

When I build my `.exe` file, right-click and go in **Details**, the **Product Version Number** field is empty.

What do I need to do to populate this field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624245/what-does-a-version-file-look-like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a version file. See the discussion [In this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624245/what-does-a-version-file-look-like) on what a version file is and how to create it, per the comment from M. R.

However, note that this is a very OS-dependent way of managing versioning. If you want to setup your scripts into a Python Package (i.e. one that can be installed with `pip`), consider using metadata from the `setuptools` package to handle your versioning.  See [the Python Packaging Docs](https://packaging.python.org/) and the [Python Packaging Tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for more details.

However, this will not put the metadata into a format that can be accessed the way you requested. One could meld the two approaches and have the OS-specific version file use the `setuptools` package metadata as its source, since it is just a python file.