# how to use Windows Version Data with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, windows, version, pyinstaller

i dont know how to use Windows Version Data with pyinstaller
i checked the doc but "For details see the Microsoft Version Information Structures page" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468916(v=vs.85).aspx

but no idea how to use it (idk C) ?

Comment: You can add a manifest file to the exe.

Comment: thx.i found this with your comment
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823824/how-do-you-add-a-manifest-to-pyinstaller-compiled-exe

Comment: No no - don't edit the code. Write your file and add it with the `--manifest=filename` option

Comment: found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624245/what-does-a-version-file-look-like